# mysql_num_rows and mysql_affected_rows return the same result when executing SELECT SQL

Tags: php, mysql-num-rows

My test code:

```
    $connection = mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', '') or die(mysql_error());

    mysql_select_db("chaoge", $connection);

    mysql_query("SET NAMES UTF8", $connection);

    $rs = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM babel_node WHERE nod_pid = 2101", $connection);

    $nu = mysql_affected_rows();
    echo $nu;
```

It says that mysql_affected_rows works with INSERT, UPDATE, REPLACE and DELETE。

Why I can also get the right result through `mysql_affected_rows` ?

Any help and suggestions will be highly appreciable。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is what I found on the internet.

> mysql_affected_rows() for a SELECT indicates the number of rows which
>   were found. mysql_num_rows() indicates how many rows were actually
>   returned. They may not be the same, IIRC, if you have a LIMIT clause
>   or similar. GROUP BY may also cause a difference.

[Source](http://bytes.com/topic/php/answers/749156-difference-between-mysql_affected_rows-mysql_num_rows)

See answers on the source at the bottom.

Comment: Thank you very much . Very helpful to me

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you must use

MySQLi http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php

or

PDO_MySQL http://php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-mysql.php

for updated method of accessing database since your method was deprecated in PHP 5.5.0